# Stop Arbitrary Posts Being Created By Non Admin User And Other unauthenticated Users In PHP On Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Need to harden the below php code, so that a capability check is carried out, which would prevent unauthorised users from creating arbitrary posts on our Wordpress site.

The code needs changing so that it isn't vulnerable to broken access control.

```
public static function check_for_saas_push() {

    if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['json_product_push'] ) || ( isset( $_REQUEST['json_product_push'] ) && 'true' !== $_REQUEST['json_product_push'] ) )
        return;

        error_reporting( E_ERROR );

        if ( ! empty( $_POST['product'] ) ) {
            $product = stripslashes( $_POST['product'] );
            $product = json_decode( $product );

            $download_url = Sputnik::API_BASE . '/download/' . $product->post_name . '.zip';
            $thumb_url    = $product->thumbnail_url;

            //Check if local product exists - if so, update it, if not, don't.
            $local = get_posts( array(
                'pagename' => $product->post_name,
                'post_type' => 'wpsc-product',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'numberposts' => 1 )
            );

            $user_check = get_user_by( 'email', $product->author_email );

            if ( $user_check ) {
                $product->post_author = $user_check->ID;

                if ( ! in_array( 'vendor-administrator', $user_check->roles ) )
                    $user_check->add_role( 'vendor-administrator' );
            }
            else {
                $product->post_author = wp_insert_user( array( 'role' => 'vendor-administrator', 'user_email' => $product->author_email, 'user_pass' => wp_generate_password(), 'user_login' => $product->author_email ) );
            }

            $product = (array) $product;
            unset( $product['guid'] );
            unset( $product['post_date_gmt'] );
            unset( $product['post_date'] );

            require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

            if ( ! empty( $local ) ) {
                $product['ID'] = $local[0]->ID;
                $new_id = wp_update_post( $product );
            } else {
                unset( $product['ID'] );
                // Doesn't exist, create it.  Then, after created, add download URL and thumbnail.
                $new_id = wp_insert_post( $product );
            }

            update_post_meta( $new_id, '_download_url', $download_url );

            foreach ( $product['meta'] as $key => $val ) {
                if ( '_wpsc_product_metadata' == $key )
                    continue;

                if ( '_wpsc_currency' == $key )
                    continue;

                update_post_meta( $new_id, $key, $val[0] );
            }



            $thumb = media_sideload_image( $thumb_url, $new_id, 'Product Thumbnail' );

            if ( ! is_wp_error( $thumb ) ) {
                $thumbnail_id = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_parent' => $new_id ) );

                if ( ! empty( $thumbnail_id ) ) {

                    $thumbnail = set_post_thumbnail( $new_id, $thumbnail_id[0]->ID );
                    echo json_encode( array( 'set_thumbnail' => $thumbnail, 'post_id' => $new_id ) );
                    die;
                }
                die;
            }
            die;
        }

    exit;
}
```

After researching online, I've found the following code, but as new to php, not sure if I'm on the right path, or whether this would be the correct code to incorporate in the above code?

```
if (current_user_can('manage_options')) {
```

Comment: Much of what you're looking for is already built into the Wordpress REST API. I would strongly suggest you use those endpoints instead of trying to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your comment checking if the user has permission is the easiest route to go.

Admins = 'manage_options' but you can make it available for editors using 'edit_others_posts'.

```
public static function check_for_saas_push() {

    if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['json_product_push'] ) || ( isset( $_REQUEST['json_product_push'] ) && 'true' !== $_REQUEST['json_product_push'] ) )
        return;

        error_reporting( E_ERROR );

        if( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {  // or use 'edit_others_posts'
            if ( ! empty( $_POST['product'] ) ) {
                // THE REST OF YOUR CODE HERE
            }
        }

    exit;

}
```

Would the below code be correct?

```
public static function check_for_saas_push() {

if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['json_product_push'] ) || ( isset( $_REQUEST['json_product_push'] ) && 'true' !== $_REQUEST['json_product_push'] ) )
    return;

    error_reporting( E_ERROR );

    if( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {  // or use 'edit_others_posts'
        if ( ! empty( $_POST['product'] ) ) {
            // THE REST OF YOUR CODE HERE
            $product = stripslashes( $_POST['product'] );
        $product = json_decode( $product );

        $download_url = Sputnik::API_BASE . '/download/' . $product->post_name . '.zip';
        $thumb_url    = $product->thumbnail_url;

        //Check if local product exists - if so, update it, if not, don't.
        $local = get_posts( array(
            'pagename' => $product->post_name,
            'post_type' => 'wpsc-product',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'numberposts' => 1 )
        );
        $product = (array) $product;
        unset( $product['guid'] );
        unset( $product['post_date_gmt'] );
        unset( $product['post_date'] );

        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

        if ( ! empty( $local ) ) {
            $product['ID'] = $local[0]->ID;
            $new_id = wp_update_post( $product );
        } else {
            unset( $product['ID'] );
            // Doesn't exist, create it.  Then, after created, add download URL and thumbnail.
            $new_id = wp_insert_post( $product );
        }

        update_post_meta( $new_id, '_download_url', $download_url );

        foreach ( $product['meta'] as $key => $val ) {
            if ( '_wpsc_product_metadata' == $key )
                continue;

            if ( '_wpsc_currency' == $key )
                continue;

            update_post_meta( $new_id, $key, $val[0] );
        }



        $thumb = media_sideload_image( $thumb_url, $new_id, 'Product Thumbnail' );

        if ( ! is_wp_error( $thumb ) ) {
            $thumbnail_id = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_parent' => $new_id ) );

            if ( ! empty( $thumbnail_id ) ) {

                $thumbnail = set_post_thumbnail( $new_id, $thumbnail_id[0]->ID );
                echo json_encode( array( 'set_thumbnail' => $thumbnail, 'post_id' => $new_id ) );
                die;
            }
            die;
        }
        die;
    }

exit;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Tony. Would my amended code below, with the full code, with your suggestion be correct, based on your answer? Still new to php, so not 100% sure?

Comment: I believe so.  I say that operating under the assumption that the code is generally working but that unauthorized/not-logged in users, are able to execute it, so all we're doing is ensuring it ONLY runs the important part for admins.

Where you place the `if( current_user_can() )` portion may need to be reviewed but I think this is what you're after.